# MySQL: Count records from one table and then update another

Tags: sql, mysql

Got 2 tables / entities, very straightforward scenario.

Table **poets** - Columns: id, poet, nation

Table **nations** - Columns: id, nation, count

Basically, **nations** to **poets** has a mapping of one to many, naturally. For example, there are 1000 poets from 60 nations. Each poet in **poets** is assigned to a nation by the nation field which contains the id of one of the nations in **nations**.

The count field of **nations** contains the number of poets in **poets** from this nation.

My question is how to use just one SQL query to count the number of poets by nation in **poets** and then update the corresponding count of that nation?

I tried:

```
UPDATE poets, nations SET nations.count = COUNT(poets.id) GROUP BY poets.nation HAVING poets.nation = nations.id
```

But it gives #1064 error. Also tried to combine WHERE clause somewhere but it still refuses to work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
UPDATE nations 
   SET count = (
       SELECT COUNT(id) 
         FROM poets 
        WHERE poets.nation = nations.id 
        GROUP BY id
       );
```

Comment: please note that for very large tables (500000+ records) this could get very slow.

Comment: Also, if nations.count is not nullable, this may result in warnings. Use an IFNULL to safeguard against this. UPDATE nations SET count = IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM poets WHERE poets.nation = nations.id GROUP BY id),0);

Comment: I don't think COUNT() can return a NULL. It'd just be 0 if no rows were found.

Comment: @dusoft is there any better way to update with count from other table if the data is large ?

Comment: Use a cron job in the background to do this regularly without affecting your website speed.

Answer (score 29):

You just do not need GROUP BY, cf.:

```
UPDATE nations SET count = (
  SELECT COUNT(id) FROM poets 
    WHERE poets.nation = nations.id);
```

Or rather, with GROUP BY, the subquery will return NULL for nations that have no poets. Without GROUP BY, the subquery will return 0 in this case.

Comment: null/0 difference with/without group by - this helped. thank u