# Update one table from another table while using count?

Tags: mysql

I have stats table with fields id(int) and timestamp(timestamp).

```
SELECT id FROM stats  GROUP BY id ORDER BY count(id) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Gives me the top 10 id's.

I want to put these id's into another table 'popular'

Popular has fields id(int), position(int) and timestamp(timestamp).

To summarize I want to create a query that will update the popular table with the "top 10" id's found in the stats table.

Comment: **what is the size of that table?** simply can save all the cumbersome by using the `SELECT ..GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `popular` (`id`,`position`,`timestamp`)
(
   SELECT `id`,COUNT(`id`),NOW() 
   FROM `stats` GROUP BY `id` 
   ORDER BY COUNT(`id`) DESC LIMIT 10
)
```

It's not *quite* an update, though. This'll put the new "top 10" entries from `stats` into `popular`, yet retain the "old top 10". A `TRUNCATE` on `popular` might be necessary before.

**UPDATE:** [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) will empty a given table. It's almost identical to `DELETE FROM` but it also resets any primary keys that are `auto_increment`.

Comment: Linus, that's right. I will not be able to use insert as it will keep adding new records. Tell me more about TRUNCATE.

Comment: I will be using PHP to disple the data from the popular table on a web page. If I TUNCATE OR DELETE this data would this lead an empty web page? even if its just for a split second, worse if there is an error. Or am I would worrying about nothing.

Comment: If you're concerned about the microseconds where `popular` is empty after the emptying and before the update, consider [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html).

Comment: OK, Linus. I still have given up on update as i just found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216175/mysql-count-records-from-one-table-and-then-update-another it seems to be similar to my question. Do you guys think It will work for my situation?

Comment: @jamjam `UPDATE` only "works" if you actually *update* an existing id's position. If other ids can make it to the top 10, you'll have to go for TRUNCATE/INSERT.

Comment: With update I was hoping to always have 10 rows in the popular table each has position of 1,2, 3 ... 10. Then somehow the count in the subquery will match the 'position' and update that way. But that properly won't work.