# MySQL: count records by value and then update another column with their count

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-update

Three very related SQL questions (I am actually using mySQL):

Assuming a people table with two columns name, country

1) How can I show the people who have fellow citizens? I can display the count of citizens by country:

```
select country, count(*) as fellow_citizens 
from people 
group by country
```

But I can't seem to show those records for which fellow_citizens is > 1. The following is invalid:

```
select name, country, count(*) as fellow_citizens 
from people 
group by country 
where fellow_citizens > 1;
```

... and would not be what I want any way since I don't want to group people.

2) To solve the above, I had the idea to store fellow_citizens in a new column.
This sounds like a variation on questions such as [MySQL: Count records from one table and then update another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216175/mysql-count-records-from-one-table-and-then-update-another). The difference is that I want to update the same table.

However the answer given there doesn't work here:

```
update people as dest 
set fellow_citizens = 
    (select count(*) from people as src where src.country = dest.country);
```

I get this error message:

> You can't specify target table 'dest' for update in FROM clause

It seems like I need to through another temporary table to do that. Can it be done without a temporary table?

3) As a variant of the above, how can I update a column with a people counter by country? I found I can update a global counter with something like:

```
set @i:=0; update people set counter = @i:=@i+1 order by country;
```

But here I would like to reset my @i counter when the value of country changes.

Is there a way to do that in mySQL without going to full-blown procedural code?

Answer (score 2):

Your select query should look something like:

```
SELECT name, country, count(*) as fellow_citizens  
FROM people  
GROUP BY country  
HAVING fellow_citizens > 1;
```

**Recommended solution**
You don't want to group, you just want to repeat the count for every person.
This data is not normalized and code like this is not a great way to do things.
However the following select will give you **all** the people and their counts:

```
SELECT p.* 
     , s.fellow_citizens
FROM people p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT country, count(*) as fellow_citizens
  FROM people  
  GROUP BY country  
  HAVING count(*) > 1) s ON (s.country = p.country)
```

If you don't want the actual count, just people from countries with more than 1 citizen, another way to write this query is (this may be faster than previous method, you have to test with your data):

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM people p
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM people p2  
        WHERE p2.country = p.country 
          AND p2.PK <> p.PK         -- the Primary Key of the table 
      )
```

**Only do this if you are facing slowness**
If you want to include the counts into the table using a update statement I suggest you use a separate count table, because at least that's somewhat normalized.

```
INSERT INTO people_counts (country, pcount)
  SELECT p.country, count(*) as peoplecount
  FROM people p
  GROUP BY p.country
ON DUPLICATE KEY pcount = VALUES(pcount)
```

Then you can join the counts table with the people data to speed up the select.

```
SELECT p.*, c.pcount
FROM people p
INNER JOIN people_counts c ON (p.country = c.country)
```

Comment: 'having' is the first piece of the answers thanks. Inner join is the second. Thanks again. The key to the 2nd question is that you can do `update country inner join (...) as counts set ...`. Only question 3 remains

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys, the anser to the last question is the `insert ... on duplicate key update` For normalization sake I have a strong preference on a separate counts table.

Comment: And I would urge you not to do any update if you can avoid it.  You have all the data you need already to provide the information you are asking for.  If you don't like my idea of a view you can still do what you need with a subquery.  I realise that an update can improve performance, but it is not guaranteed always to be up-to-date.

Comment: @HughJones, you can force the up-to-date-ness by putting the update code in a trigger.

Comment: @Johan Of course, but triggers should be avoided if possible.  In my opinion this is heading further down a possibly mistaken route because of the way the question was phrased.  Denormalisation is acceptable for performance reasons but do we know that the OP has performance worries ?

Comment: I don't have performance worries: this is for a one-time job to migrate data to a system I don't have control over. So while I agree with the normalization considerations, I'm stuck with what I have. I am free to use a separate table only as a temporary step. In the end, any temporary table will be dropped.

Comment: to be crystal clear, the target system **mandates** a people counter per country in the same table.

Comment: @Jean-Denis Muys, I see.  One of the questions you asked was if this could be done without a temporary table, my answer to that is yes.

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys, that's just about the **worst** solution from a performance, normalization and maintainance point of view.

Answer (score 1):

1 ->

```
select country, count(*) as fellow_citizens 
from people 
group by country 
having fellow_citizens > 1
```

Sorry, but could not really understand points 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this.

```
create view citizencount as
select country, count(*) citizens 
from people 
group by country
```

Then your Query becomes (Something like)

```
select p.personid, p.country, cc.citizens -1 fellow_citizens
from people p
join citizencount cc on
  cc.country = p.country
```

You might then want to add

> `where fellow_citizens > 0`

Comment: @jean-Denis Muys - any comment ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this for both of your problem

```
select name, fellow_citizens
from people left join  
(select country, count(*) as fellow_citizens  
 from people group by country  
 having fellow_citizens > 1) as citizens  
 on people.country = citizens.country
```

I am not very good at writing sql query; but I think this can solve your problem

Comment: I realized 'having' was the key to the 1st question. Thanks

Comment: @jean-Denis Muys - except that you dont really need it.  Fellow Citizens is always total citizens -1.

Comment: I intentionally ignored that detail. When I have one, I have the other. But it still seems that "having" is key to computer either.