# MySQL: UPDATE table with COUNT from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I thought this would be simple but I can't get my head around it...

I have one table `tbl1` and it has columns `id`,`otherstuff`,`num`.

I have another table `tbl2` and it has columns `id`,`info`.

What I want to is make the `num` column of `tbl1` equal to the number of rows with the same `id` in `tbl2`. Kind of like this:

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET num =
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl2 WHERE id=tbl1.id)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you give it a try? Looks a lot like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1216185/1037210) answer.

Comment: How weird. I didn't think what I wrote was correct SQL.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your num column is a valid numeric type your query should work as is:

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET num = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl2 WHERE id=tbl1.id)
```

Answer (score 12):

```
UPDATE tbl1, (select id, count(*) as idCount from tbl2 group by id) as t2
SET    tbl1.num = t2.idCount
WHERE  tbl1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: This was the perfect solution that is extremely fast on large tables. Thank you.

Comment: what does this do when there are 0 corresponding columns for a tbl1 row?