# How to get rid of the php wrapping on this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

I have two tables. One is production table with posts and other is the collection of posts's views.

Once a hour, all post views get grouped together and main production table gets updated. And post's views table gets truncated.

**My objective** is to get this function into pure SQL, so I could run it inside database engine as scheduled event.

SQL is my weakest point, and I can make it work with SELECT being inside one UPDATE. But if there are two UPDATE queries, then I need some sort of variable.

**This is where I started:**

```
<?  
# find new views grouped together:
$find_views = db::query("SELECT `post_id`, COUNT(*) AS `post_views` FROM `posts__views` WHERE `date_imported` IS NULL GROUP BY `post_id`;");
while ($view = db::fetch($find_views)) {

    # Update the main production tables views_count column:
    db::query("UPDATE `posts` SET `views_count` = views_count + {$view['post_views']} WHERE `id` = '{$view['post_id']}';");

    # Update the post's views table... but why does it actually needs this update hmm..
    db::query("UPDATE `posts__views` SET `date_imported` = NOW() WHERE `date_imported` IS NULL AND `post_id` = '{$view['post_id']}';");
}

# Trunkate post's views:
db::query("TRUNCATE TABLE `posts__views`;");
```

I realised, that I can make the code right away optimised, by removing the second UPDATE. And I think I can also remove date_imported completely, as all views get parsed and then truncated.

Which means, that I could most likely do `UPDATE ... WHERE (SELECT ...)`. Only problem is that, I know how to do UPDATE with SELECT in it, for one variable. But since I have `$view['post_views']` and `$view['post_id']` in the same UPDATE query, then I am hopeless lost.

**EDIT**
This is not a duplicate to:
[MySQL: UPDATE table with COUNT from another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059698/mysql-update-table-with-count-from-another-table)
As there is no truncate there. It works on the basis, that views table stays as is, with old views in place to calculate each time. I truncate the table, so rows from main table, with no new views is being SET to 0.

**EDIT 2**
So I have gotten this far:

```
UPDATE `posts` SET `views_count` = views_count + (SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `views` FROM `posts__views` WHERE `post_id` = `posts`.`id` GROUP BY `post_id` HAVING COUNT(`id`) > 0)
```

No thanks to marking this question duplicate. As I cannot find any method to make sure, that other rows, that do not have views do not get set to 0. So the innner-SELECT should come out, and outer-UPDATE should have WHERE clause. In theory like this (but this doesnt' look optimised at all):

```
UPDATE `posts` SET `views_count` = views_count + (SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `views` FROM `posts__views` WHERE `post_id` = `posts`.`id` GROUP BY `post_id` HAVING COUNT(`id`) > 0) WHERE (SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `views` FROM `posts__views` WHERE `post_id` = `posts`.`id` GROUP BY `post_id` HAVING COUNT(`id`) > 0) > 0;
```

Comment: **WARNING**: You're stuffing values directly in your SQL which is how you get nasty [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You should always strive to use prepared statements with placeholder values. It's not clear what database driver this is, but if it supports that you should be using them. If not, you **must** escape any and all user data values.

Comment: @tadman Yes, they are protected.

Comment: What honestly happened to this site. You used to get help, now you make as detailed question as possible and someone marks it as dupe, linking completely random question.

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas It's the unfortunate result of home work dumps and the flood of no research questions. (Plus a sprinkling of "mark as dupe rather close and delete for any other reason".)

Comment: @robinCTS I mean ive been a member for 6 years, this Shadow character has been 2 years. I mean, I honestly come here asking questions in the last desperate state, where I have been stuck for at least a week. And honestly, SO has reached the point, that absolutely all questions have been answered -- I agree. But If I cannot find it in a week, then what else am I supposed to do? And classic thing is, that when I don't get a reply in the first 30min, the question will go in a blackhole. Now I cannot even tag this dude, to giving him a piece of my mind.

Comment: Well, at least the question's been reopened now. The only thing I can suggest to help is, in future, keep track of any questions/answers you find on Stack Overflow when searching that are similar to what you are after, and include links to them, and a brief description of why they don't answer your question, when you post your question. If the current question is really important you could always drop a bounty on it to give it more attention.

Comment: Is stored procedure an option?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Yes.