# How to UPDATE with SELECT COUNT(), but only when count exists avoiding setting all rows to 0

Tags: mysql, sql

So I tried to ask this question already, which was set to duplicate, wasting my time basically as it had nothing to do with the duplicate-question.

[How to get rid of the php wrapping on this sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662733/how-to-get-rid-of-the-php-wrapping-on-this-sql-query)

I have gotten so far, that I can affect the rows, that have new views. Sadly however, all other's will go to 0.

```
UPDATE `posts` SET `views_count` = views_count + (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `views` FROM `posts__views` WHERE `post_id` = `posts`.`id` GROUP BY `post_id`);
```

So I think, I need some WHERE, inside the first UPDATE to avoid affecting the rows, with 0 views.

After the UPDATE call, the posts__views table gets truncated. Otherwise the above would work.

**EDIT:** My objective is to update the **posts** table `views_count`, counting and grouping up the single views from **posts__views** table. After the main SQL process, the **posts__views** gets truncated and new views will be generated.

Originally the code was in PHP like so:

```
<?  
# find new views grouped together:
$find_views = db::query("SELECT `post_id`, COUNT(*) AS `post_views` FROM `posts__views` WHERE `date_imported` IS NULL GROUP BY `post_id`;");
while ($view = db::fetch($find_views)) {

    # Update the main production tables views_count column:
    db::query("UPDATE `posts` SET `views_count` = views_count + {$view['post_views']} WHERE `id` = '{$view['post_id']}';");

    # Update the post's views table... but why does it actually needs this update hmm..
    db::query("UPDATE `posts__views` SET `date_imported` = NOW() WHERE `date_imported` IS NULL AND `post_id` = '{$view['post_id']}';");
}

# Trunkate post's views:
db::query("TRUNCATE TABLE `posts__views`;");
```

Comment: it is unclear what you want to do

Comment: You should include a sqlfiddel ( http://sqlfiddle.com/ ) and expected output.. Your new question or your linked question isn't complete at all.

Comment: @JoshuaKisubi Thank you for your reply. I have added further details and the original PHP part, to illustrate trough code what I am trying to achieve. Ultimate goal is to make this php process into sql.

Comment: if i understand you correctly you would like to only update views_count when there is a match in posts__views WHERE `post_id` = `posts`.`id`?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am not sure, if this is correct, but: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9787bf/2 Also to answer your other questions, then yes. I want to update posts.views_count with total counts of rows from posts__views, the the truncate at the end. So only to affect rows, where there are new views in the posts__views. Right now it works only for the posts with new views. Others get zero views. As the count is obviously zero.