# insert count from another table onto master table

Tags: mysql

I've got one master table and several additional tables. Each row is a individual person's record.

I want to insert an individual's counts from the additional table as new columns onto the master table. There is a unique ID that can link the two.

I found these instructions: [MySQL: UPDATE table with COUNT from another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059698/mysql-update-table-with-count-from-another-table)

My code is:

```
SELECT * FROM leeds.salesforce_contacts as allmemcomb
    LEFT OUTER JOIN leeds.leenk_ladder_history as ladhist on allmemcomb.salesforce_id = ladhist.member_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN leeds_so.leenk_ladder_config as ladconf on ladhist.member_id = ladconf.ladder_config_id

UPDATE allmemb
set count = (
    select count (ladder_change)
    from ladhist where ladhist.member_id = allmembcomb.salesforce_id
        );
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE allmemb  set count = (   select count (ladder_change)   from ladhist wher' at line 13
```

thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the semicolon at the end of the statement before UPDATE.

Comment: Hmm. 

Got: 
` Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE allmemb  set `count` = (   select count (ladder_change)   from ladhist wh' at line 13` 

I updated it to: 

` UPDATE allmemb
 set `count` = (
  select count (ladder_change)
  from ladhist where ladhist.member_id = allmembcomb.salesforce_id
   ); `

Comment: Maybe you are simply missing the semicolon at the end of the statement before UPDATE?

Comment: AH! That was it. Thank you.